# Django get_FOO_display on template wont display

Tags: django

Good day SO. I am trying to use the get_FOO_display on template but my data is not displaying. Also, I have read other SO answers and I believe that I followed them to a T but not working. Please try to correct me what I do wrong.

How I declared:

Models:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (1, '男性'),
    (2, '女性'),
)

gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=0, null=False)
```

forms:

```
...
self.fields['gender'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

view:

```
account = AccountViewForm(initial = {"gender" : account.gender})
```

template:

```
{{account.get_gender_display}}
```

If I only use `{{account.gender}}`, it becomes a select tag with the correct data. I want to display this as a TEXT tag.

Note. I also cant do `<input type="text" value="{{account.gender}}" id="id_gender">` manually since this messes up the template.

Comment: You already have your answer. {{account.gender}} is how you get it to display

Comment: I want to display it as a text, not a select.

Comment: @rodjames Since you don't want a form why are you using one? Just pass the account object in the template.

Comment: Oh. sorry, I thought I need to pass the form to template and use the get_FOO_display.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're passing the .gender property, you need the whole model instance that contains the .gender attribute (Account model?)

the `.get_FOO_display` exists on the model as whole, not the field.

pass the `account` object in the `context` and use `account_obj.get_foo_display()`